# What does the number represent?

Tags: support, globalinbox

When I click the StackExchange button and select hot questions, there is a number next to the questions. What is that number suppose to represent? I have tried looking at, adding, subtracting and so on... the votes, comments, and number of the views, but nothing adds up.

I can click on the number and it will bring me to the question.

[image: what is this]

Answer (score 3):

This number is the question's hotness. One definition is available [on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions), but my results are off for some reason by what seems to be a constant factor. Still, it should be good enough to get an idea what's considered relevant.